# Adding only devise :confirmable to a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

I need to add a confirmation email functionality to a model in a Rails Application, but nothing else. It is not a User model, it is not authenticable.

I added `devise :confirmable` to the Model, and ran the migration:

```
class AddConfirmableToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :projects, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :projects, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :projects, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    add_index :projects, :confirmation_token, :unique => true
  end

  def down
    remove_column :projects, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at
  end
end
```

But when I create a new Project I get: `Could not find a valid mapping for #<Project...`

Comment: [How To: Add :confirmable to Users](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit wierd to add :confirmable to a model that's not your User model. Are you sure about this?

> ```
> # Confirmable is responsible to verify if an account is already confirmed to
> # sign in, and to send emails with confirmation instructions.
> ```

If **yes**, is this an error returning after running your Spec/Tests? If you're running FactoryGirl with RSpec try adding `config.cache_classes = true` in the test.rb file. This is a bit shady, but looks like the only solution.

If **no**, please provide some more code (model, controller, view).

Comment: I want to do this to verify users' email addresses: people are able to upload something to the app but they need to confirm their email after doing so. One time only. It is failing under normal circumstances, no rspec.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can setup confirmable to any model. Following are the steps to do this. Lets say I have model a `Invitation`:

1. Add `devise :confirmable` to `Invitation`
2. This model should have the attribute `:email`
3. Create a migration with the following columns:

   ```
   t.string   "email"
   t.string   "confirmation_token"
   t.datetime "confirmed_at"
   t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
   ```
4. Create a controller which needs to extend `Devise::ConfirmationsController`. Add the following code in that controller:

   ```
   def create
     self.resource = resource_class.send_confirmation_instructions(params[resource_name])
     if successful_and_sane?(resource)
       respond_with({}, :location => root_url)
     else
       # code your logic
     end
   end

   def new; end

   def show; end
   ```

   - Create an email view `confirmation_instruction.html.erb` under "app/views/devise/mailer/"
   - Following line will create confirmation URL in your email: `<%= confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %>`
   - Now create new record of your model "Invitation" by `Invitation.create(:email => params[:email]`
   - Now on successful create, record will be saved in DB and email will send to that email as well.